# How to get videos of channel by channel ID without use search request

Tags: node.js, youtube-api

In my NodeJS application, I use this code to get the videos for a specific channel:

```
 var myOauth = 'my oauth object';
 var channelId = 'my channel id';
 youtube.search.list({ auth: myOauth, part: 'snippet', 
                       channelId: channelId, type:'video',
                       order:'date', maxResults:50 
                     }, 
                     function(err, response) {
                       //do something here
                     }
 );
```

This solution works but the quota cost of each request is 100. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

I want to get videos with other way like "playlistItems" where the quota cost is 1. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Comment: How do you get this `youtube` object ? From which library ?

Comment: from the youtube api v3.

You can get this library here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

A complete example in nodejs is here:
https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/youtube

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@julien-dumortier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388976)'s question post.

> I found a new method to get videos of specific channel by channel id with only 3 quota cost.
>
> Get the subscription list of user authenticated with Oauth:
>
> ```
> youtube.subscriptions.list({
>     auth: oauth, part: 'snippet,contentDetails', 
>     mine:true, maxResults:50, 
>     pageToken:pageToken }, 
>     function(err, response) {
>         if(!err) {
>             var firstChannelId = response.item[0].snippet.resourceId.channelId;
>             console.log(firstChannelId);
>         }
>     }
> );
> ```
>
> Get the channel playlist ID from channel ID:
>
> ```
> youtube.channels.list({    auth: res.oauth, part: 'contentDetails', 
>     id:firstChannelId, maxResults:50 }, 
>     function(err, response) {
>         var channelPlaylistId = response.item[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
>         console.log(channelPlaylistId);
>     }
> );
> ```
>
> Browse items from playlist:
>
> ```
> youtube.playlistItems.list({    auth: res.oauth, part: 'snippet', 
>     playlistId:channelPlaylistId,
>     maxResults:50, pageToken:pageToken }, 
>     function(err, response) {
>         console.log(JSON.stringify(response.items));
>     }
> );
> ```